# async/await exception handling pattern

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have the following reoccurring try/catch pattern in my code. Using a try/catch block to handle any exceptions thrown when calling a method in orionProxy.

```
async private void doGetContacts()
{
    try {
        currentContacts = await orionProxy.GetContacts (); // call method in orionProxy
        ShowContacts (); // do something after task is complete
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        orionProxy.HandleException (e); // handle thrown exception
    }
}
```

What I would like to write is something like the following.

```
async private void doGetContacts()
{
    currentContacts = await orionProxy.CheckForException(orionProxy.GetContacts ());
    ShowContacts (); // do something after task is complete but shouldn't run on exception
}
```

Any pointers/suggestions? I've tried various forms of Actions/Tasks/Lambdas but nothing will properly trap the exception in orionProxy.CheckForException(?) so ShowContacts doesn't run.

Comment: Tasks will throw an `AggregateException`. Is that what you're trying to catch? Or are you trying to catch a specific exception?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't work, assuming `GetContacts` is an `async` method:

```
public async Task<T> CheckForExceptionAsync<T>(Task<T> source)
{
  try
  {
    return await source;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    HandleException(ex);
    return default(T);
  }
}
```

On a side note, you should [avoid `async void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (as I describe in my MSDN article) and [end your `async` method names with the `Async` suffix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I still need to check if result = null (if (currentContacts != null) ShowContacts();) but the pattern is clean.

Comment: If I call your above method `await CheckForExceptionAsync` it throws an aggregate exception in code rather than trapping it. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: Not unless `HandleException` throws an `AggregateException`. If you have a reproducible case, feel free to post it as a question.

Comment: I think it was an outside issue in my code. Thanks for the reply.