# Create a simple Query object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a query as follows:

```
public class FindPostEditModelByIdQuery : IQuery<PostEditModel> {

  private readonly ILogger _logger;
  private readonly ISession _session;

  public FindPostEditModelByIdQuery(ISession session, ILogger logger) {
    _logger = logger;
    _session = session;        
  }

  public async Task<PostEditModel> Run(int postId, out exception) {
    // Code here
  }

}
```

So basically on the constructor I am requesting through IOC what I will use ...

This approach allows, I hope, to use async in an easy way an keep things simple.

A few questions:

1. In my controllers I will use many commands ...
   I would like to avoid having a lot of them on the constructor.
   Do you think injecting a factory that requests a command would be ok?
   How should I do this?
2. Am I using async correctly?
3. What do you think about passing the exception as a parameter?
   Would be possible to create something that would log an exception the momment it occurs on the Run methods. Does this even make sense?

**UPDATE**

What I post is a try to make it easier to use async when compared to what I am using.

I am using Queries / Replies and Commands (I called them orders at the time) and I have:

```
public interface IOrderHandler {
  void Handle(Order order);
}
public interface IOrderHandler<TOrder> : IOrderHandler where TOrder : Order {
  void Handle(TOrder order);
}
public interface IQueryHandler {
  Reply Handle(Query query);
}
public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TReply> : IQueryHandler
  where TQuery : Query
  where TReply : Reply {
  Reply Handle(TQuery query);
}

public abstract class OrderHandler : IOrderHandler {
  public abstract void Handle(Order order); // Handle
}
public abstract class OrderHandler<TOrder> : OrderHandler, IOrderHandler<TOrder> where TOrder : Order {
  public override void Handle(Order order) {
    TOrder torder = (TOrder)order;
    Handle(torder);
  }
  public abstract void Handle(TOrder order); // Handle
}

public abstract class QueryHandler<TQuery, TReply> : QueryHandler, IQueryHandler<TQuery, TReply>
where TQuery : Query
where TReply : Reply {
  public override Reply Handle(Query query) {
    TQuery tquery = (TQuery)query;
    Reply treply = Handle(tquery);
    return treply;
  }
  public abstract Reply Handle(TQuery query);
}

public abstract class QueryHandler : IQueryHandler {
  public abstract Reply Handle(Query query);
}

public abstract class QueryHandler<TQuery, TReply> : QueryHandler, IQueryHandler<TQuery, TReply>
  where TQuery : Query
  where TReply : Reply {
  public override Reply Handle(Query query) {
    TQuery tquery = (TQuery)query;
    Reply treply = Handle(tquery);
    return treply;
  }
  public abstract Reply Handle(TQuery query);
}

public abstract class Order { } // Order

public abstract class Query { }

public abstract class Reply {
  public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

public interface IDispatcher {
  void Send(Order order);
  void Send(Order order, out Exception exception);
  TReply Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new();
}

public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {

  public void Send(Order order) {

    Type type = typeof(IOrderHandler<>).MakeGenericType(order.GetType());
    IOrderHandler handler = (IOrderHandler)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);

    try {
      handler.Handle(order);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
      logger.Send(exception);
      if (Debugger.IsAttached) throw;
    }

  }

  public void Send(Order order, out Exception exception) {
    Type type = typeof(IOrderHandler<>).MakeGenericType(order.GetType());
    IOrderHandler handler = (IOrderHandler)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);
    exception = null;
    try {
      handler.Handle(order);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
      logger.Send(ex);
      exception = ex;
      if (Debugger.IsAttached) throw;
    }

  }

  public TReply Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {

    Type type = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TReply));

    IQueryHandler handler = (IQueryHandler)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);

    try {
      return (TReply)handler.Handle(query);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
      logger.Send(exception);
      if (Debugger.IsAttached) throw;
      return new TReply { Exception = exception };
    }
  }

} // Dispatcher
```

**A FEW NOTES AND QUESTIONS**

1. It is the dispatcher I am injecting on my controllers. And then I use it:

   _dispacther.Send(new FindPostByIdQuery(22));
2. I am not sure if logging the exceptions in the dispatcher is a good approach.
   Basically I am logging all exceptions that occur on the service layer.

   One thing I was considering was having an ExceptionHandler which could be attached.

   But I am not sure if this could be possible. **What do you think?**
3. I am not sure how to make my code to work with async if I need it.
4. Does anyone knows how to test this pattern? It has not been easy for me.

Comment: Your `FindPostEditModelByIdQuery` mixes data and behavior. This makes it very hard test stuff in isolation and makes it hard to apply cross-cutting concerns. Instead, take a look at [this related design](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: I added more information and why it has been hard to me to use async.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. It seems you actually read that article :-)

Comment: Hey, can you post or link gists of your complete classes? I might be able to take a stab...

Comment: @Mrchief Sorry for the delay ... Different time zone. I just updated my code with all I have (Let me know if you need more info). At the end I added a few notes and questions.

Comment: I've a rough idea, which I can update my answer with. It won't be copy/paste code so you may have to tweak it a bit to get it working, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction. Let me know if that's ok with you.

Answer (score 2):

#1: Your controller should not be using that many injected commands. [Constructor over injection](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/constructor-over-injection-anti-pattern/) is usually a smell that the object needs to be broken down further. Concerns like logging, exception handling are often cross cutting and they are better handled at an outer layer.

#2: There is barely any code to be able to say anything conclusively. Signature-wise this is ok, although like I said above, you can probably do away with `out exception`. The caller needs to handle the fault in a async chain using `ContinueWith` or [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148540/244353).

```
task.ContinueWith(x => x.Exception.Handle(ex =>
                  {
                      logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                      return false;
                  }), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

#3: Exception logging should not be the responsibility of the query object, rather something that sits above it - using action filters, or at the caller level or a service or better - using aspect oriented programming.

**Update:**

Take a look at [ShortBus](https://github.com/mhinze/ShortBus). Unless you want to DIY, this has all the things you're looking for, including [async handlers](https://github.com/mhinze/ShortBus/blob/master/ShortBus/Handlers.cs#L10), ability to [bubble up exceptions](https://github.com/mhinze/ShortBus/blob/master/ShortBus.Tests/Example/BasicExample.cs#L96) and unit tests.

Comment: I added more information on what I am using now and why I was considering moving.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @Mrchief on constructor over injection. Consider splitting the controllers in smaller parts. I would say that usually your controller should have just one command handler (or two at most).

Comment: I find this incredibly simple and easy to follow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23534126/244353

Comment: @Steven: And looks like I totally agree with you (see my previous comment!). I absolutely love your blog posts about "meanwhile on the query/command side..."