# object is always not null

Tags: c#, async-await

This has always driven me crazy and I still cant get my head around it. In the code below, the if statement is flagged by the editor saying that the "expression is always true"

```
 public Task ConfigSendMailAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {

        const string usertoken = "Sent";
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("service@tradertoolkit.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        mailMessage.Body = message.Body;


        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                   );

         var mailClient = new SmtpClient {Credentials = credentials};

        ***if (mailClient != null)***
        {
            mailClient.SendAsync(mailMessage, usertoken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        else
        {
            //log error
            return Task.FromResult(-1);
        }
    }
```

How is it always true, what if the message that was passed was invalid, what if there was a failure creating the credentials, etc. etc. Certainly something COULD make that if statement true. I get that if anything failed prior, I'd get an exception. If I wanted to ensure the credential was valid, Id certainly test for that.

```
 if (credentials != null)
        {

        }
```

But guess what, apparently thats always true as well. How can that be, what if there was nothing stored in those app settings? Can someone explain how this actually works and how best to structure this code

Comment: You assign it directly above, since a constructor can't return null, it will always *not* be null. Why do you want to check for null there? As the compiler says, it can't possibly be null, so the check isn't required.

Comment: You're assigning a value. If that assignment fails, then there'd be some exception. It's fair to assume the value is not null.

Comment: `var mailClient = new SmtpClient {Credentials = credentials};`. The only way for `mailClient` to not be assigned a value is if there is an exception that blows everything up (in which case you'll never reach the `if` statement). In all cases where you reach the `if` statement, `mailClient` will contain the `SmtpClient` instance you're instantiating in the assignment statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the `SmtpClient` object does not check the credentials for validity. It will just store them in fields for later use. The constructor will create a new object and the object will not be null. Conclusion: the if statement is always `true`.

What will happen though: the `SendAsync()` method may throw a [SmtpException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x5x13z6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if credentials don't work. You'd need to catch the exception.

Comment: I originally had it in a try catch but the editor doesn't like the await in the try block

Comment: @dinotom: Really? [It should work ...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19148540/480982)

Comment: I'll add to the post when I get home in an hour, enroute now

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you have, mailClient is never null, because your code just instantiated it.  If there were a problem with the instantiation, the line *above* would have failed.

```
 var mailClient = new SmtpClient {Credentials = credentials};  //This line would throw an error if SmtpClient could not be instantiated
 if (mailClient == null)
 {
    throw new Exception("This will never happen.");
 }
```

You would need the null check only if you are using some function or factory pattern to create the object instance, e.g.

```
 var mailClient = SmtpHelper.CreateClient(credentials);
 if (mailClient == null)
 {
     throw new Exception("SmtpHelper returned a null client!");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How is it always true, what if the message that was passed was
>   invalid, what if there was a failure creating the credentials, etc.
>   etc.

In that case, perhaps an exception would be thrown, and the `if` would never be reached. You can trust the compiler on this one.

Same for credentials: You give an example of invalid credentials. They would be invalid, sure, but not null.

The only way you could have your if to return false would be if you  swallow an exception occuring in the constructor (which would be a *terrible* idea, and the compiler would detect it and not display that warning any longer)

for instance:

```
 try
 {
     var mailClient = new SmtpClient {Credentials = credentials};
 }
 catch(Exception)
 {
     // Evil: you swallow your exception, mailClient is null
     // The program continues and god drowns a kitten.
 }

 if (mailClient != null)
 {
     mailClient.SendAsync(mailMessage, usertoken);
     return Task.FromResult(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

mailClient is never `null`

You just new'd it up. Maybe the field/property is null, that's not what you're checking there. Maybe something went terribly wrong and an exception was thrown and mailClient was never assigned, but then you wouldn't have got to that check.

Also [this is how you write asynchronous code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async). Also, it's not SQL, we don't comminicate whether an method worked by returning a weakly typed integer.

Answer (score 0):

*The condition `(mailClient != null)` is only a reference check.*

If the variable `mailClient` would be a dangling pointer, this condition would fail. As long as you have a valid space carved out in memory with `mailClient` pointing to that memory space, it is not null.

The conditional that you are concerned with would ask - Does the `mailClient` point to anything valid? And the CLR would find out - *Yes, the value in the reference type variable called `mailClient` is valid.* The conditional would then be `true` as it is not null.

When you do `var xyz = new Something();` you reserve a piece of memory and the variable now points to that memory in the heap. Even if you have not populated the fields of that member, the address stored in `xyz` not null anymore and that is how your conditional is always `true`.

---

Opposed to that, let's say you have a statement `Something xyz;`. All this means that `xyz` can store the address of a `Something` type object. However, this variable does not point to any valid address in memory space yet and is just a dangling pointer. This will cause your conditional check of `(xyz != null)` to fail.